# How to Click a ToggleSwitch control inside a Button content without triggering the Button click event

Tags: events, togglebutton, mahapps.metro, eventtrigger

In a WPF project I have the following scenario:

- I'm using MahApps.Metro framework.
- I have a button that navigates to some page.
- The button has a ToggleSwitch control inside its content.

Whenever I click the ToggleSwitch, the parent Button click event is triggered. How to prevent this behaviour?

[image: MahApps.Metro framework controls event priority]

```
<Button x:Name="btn1" Height="40" BorderThickness="0" Width="auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" Style="{DynamicResource SquareButtonStyle}" Click="Button_Click">
       <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                       <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                       <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                       <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                       <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="auto" Grid.Column="1">Services</TextBlock>
            <Controls:ToggleSwitch Grid.Column="3" x:Name="enabledSwitch4"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    Width="Auto"
                                    Style="{StaticResource MahApps.Metro.Styles.ToggleSwitch.Win10}"
                                    OnLabel="" OffLabel=""
                                    IsChecked="True" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        </Grid>
</Button>
```

Comment: Why do you need this ToggleSwitsch inside the Button content?

Comment: The design of the project I'm working on requires this.

basically, there is a navigation sidebar, and the user has the option to turn on/off some services from any page he is in now.

Comment: So you want to enable/disable the button click action with the toggle button? Or what do you do at the click event of the button and the toggle switch?

Comment: There is a ContentControl,

each button in the sidebar changes the content of the ContentControl with a specific UserControl.

The ToggleSwitch is used to turn on/off some background service.

What I need is allowing to click the ToggleSwitsch to control the background service without executing the (parent) Button click event.

When I click the ToggleSwitch now, the Button click event fires since its a parent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can handle/prevent this at the Button's click event.

```
private async void ButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.OriginalSource != sender)
    {
        // do nothing if clicked the ToggleSwitch
        e.Handled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        // handle the button click action
        await this.ShowMessageAsync(string.Empty, "Yeah, you clicked the real button!");
    }
}
```

[image]